# Accessing GetStream.io Reactions from Ruby

Tags: ruby, getstream-io

There is no documentation on the GetStream.io site for the Ruby client when it comes to reactions, but I tried `client.reactions.add('like', activity_id, user_id: user.id)` and it says there's no method `reactions` for Stream::Client.

Help?

Comment: What are reactions? Have you set up a relationship between them and clients? Show us the code for both models please

Comment: These are not models, they're GetStream.io items. This isn't about Rails, it's about the Stream API library.

Comment: Whoops, my bad!

Comment: Stream::Client does not seem to have any method relating to reactions (check `client.methods - Object.new.methods`)... Maybe you can implement it yourself using `make_request` ?